# Insert values with select Postgres

Tags: sql, postgresql, join, select, sql-insert

I need to make an insert, but before I need to compare the values ​​of the insert with other tables, so that I can also insert the values ​​of other tables, in the current table that I want to insert:

[image]

I don't know how to write the insert syntax

```
Insert into TABLE_3 (code, value, description)
values 123, 20000, teste
```

Answer (score 2, accepted):

Consider the `insert ... select ...` syntax. The [`values()` list](https://www.postgresql.org/docs/current/queries-values.html) comes handy for this.

```
insert into table_3(code, value, desription, subscription, value_percent, total_value)
select
    v.code,
    v.value,
    v.description,
    t1.subscription,
    t2.value_percent,
    v.value * t2.value_percent / 100.0 total_value
from (values (123, 20000, 'teste')) v(code, value, description)
inner join table_1 t1 on t1.code = v.code
inner join table_2 t2 on t2.subscription = t1.subscription
```

Comment: I still need to do one last test to run the last inner join only if there is t1.code, if there is not, then you don't need to run it. t1.code IS NOT NULL

Comment: can help me please?

Comment: @rbrt: that's what the query does. If there is no match on `t1.code`, the row is not inserted.

Comment: I needed to return null on the missing columns.

The columns that can be null are t1.subscription.

This is posible?

Comment: @rbrt: ok, then you want `left join`s instead of `inner join`s. First change the last `inner join` to a `left join`, see if it does what you want. If that's not enough then change both.